# Should [panoramas] and [panoramic] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Recently, I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422968/360-degrees-panorama-in-jquery) that was tagged both [panoramas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramas) and [panoramic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramic). Should these be merged, since they are so similar?

**EDIT To clarify:**
[panoramic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramic) has no tag wiki. The tag wiki for [panoramas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramas) says a panorama is "any wide-angle view or representation of a physical space, whether in painting, drawing, photography, film, or a three-dimensional model". The 29 questions under [panoramic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramic) all seem to fall under [panoramas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panoramas).

Comment: If you want your request to be taken more seriously, I'd suggest you provide more explanation.  Just saying "these are similar" is not a good reason to synonymize tags.  Why do you think they are similar?  The [tag:panoramic] tag does not have a wiki so why do you think they are similar?  Are you just basing this on the name?  Or did you review the individual questions?  Do all (or most) of the questions on the [tag:panoramic] tag match the [tag:panoramas] tag to suggest the usage is similar?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've never suggested merging tags before, thanks for helping. I updated the question.

Comment: Yes, please do update your question with details.  I have reviewed most of the questions and think you are right.  There are only a few questions that don't fit that I have found.  99% of them are referring to the Panorama Control on Windows Phone, so I am fixing those tags now.

Answer (score 1):

The synonym has been created.  This task is done.